# Best way to create dynamic footer depending on the view, android

Tags: android, footer

I am creating an application. in every screen of the application I have to add **footer**. If the **orientation** change to **landscape** then there should be no **footer** otherwise there should be **footer**. in that **footer** there should be three buttons. if i am in first page then first page will be in selected if i am in second page then second button should be selected. I want this type of  functionality. To achieve this i can create a **footer** layout and add in the xml of every screen but i want to select the buttons depending on the page and also hide or show the **footer** depending on the **orientation**. How can I achieve this?

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To deal with showing/hiding the footer I do this at the end of my `onCreate` method:

   if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
                   footer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }
2. To deal with selecting the button just add a line of code that selects the appropriate button based on the activity.

Comment: I have another concern can i create a single layout for footer and use it everywhere or. Can you show some sample examples?

Comment: You can create a single layout for the footer and include it everywhere. I haven't personally done it but http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html shows some information about using `include` to do what you want.